# Install Sump Basin in Existing Basement

Tags: basement, sump-pump

So I've been having issues with water seeping into my basement through the cement floor.  I do have a sump pit and a sump pump, but the house had an addition put on many years ago that included an addition to the basement on the opposite side of the house from where the sump pit is.

I suspect that the water under the new side of the basement is not properly draining into the sump pit in the original part of the basement. So I've been thinking about putting in a second sump pit & pump in the added-on area of the basement (which is where the water has been infiltrating).

In researching this, it looks like all sump pits are set up to accept corrugated pipes from a foundation drain system.  I don't want to bust up a large part of the basement floor to put those pipes in, and I have no idea where the existing drainage pipes would be (if there are any at all).  I was thinking about simply perforating the plastic sides/bottom of one of those plastic sump pits, wrapping it in a few layers of landscaping fabric to prevent dirt from coming in, and installing the pit that way.  If there is gravel under the basement floor, then hopefully water would drain through there and make it's way into the sump pit through the perforations even without any drain pipes.

Is this a reasonable solution?  Or am I just totally setting myself up for failure here?  How would you normally add a sump pit into an existing basement without busting up huge parts of the concrete slab for drainage pipes?

Comment: Yes, but as you said it depends entirely on the slab's substrate being highly permeable. If it is, why isn't it draining to the existing tile?

Comment: I'd maybe rent a core drill and put a 3" hole in the slab. Dig down a foot or so and see how things drain.

Comment: @isherwood - my thought was that the drainage pipes from the added-on part of the basement aren't connected to the tile from the old side of the basement and that might be why the water isn't draining to the existing tile.

Comment: Right. If you have gravel that flows well, though, it should be flowing to the existing drain tile, yes?

Comment: How old is the addition? can you find who pulled the permit? Talk to the inspector. There should be records or plans. You said "a few years ago" so the information should be available. If you created a pit, you know you now have to keep it there and active because you created the entry point. Therefore, if it doesn't work, you'll be cutting up the basement perimeter eventually to drain tile. And at least part of the job would be complete already.

Comment: @noybman - The house was built in '73 and the addition was put on sometime in the late 80s or early 90s I think.  If the person who did it was still around, I doubt if they would remember the job.  I might be able to check to see if there are any plans on file with the township though.  I haven't done anything yet, just trying to do my research before I start busting up my basement floor and get past that point of no return :)